# Converting Handlebars to React Mapping Syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handlebars.js, marionette, jsx

Getting an error at the following line:

```
data.Values.Volumes.map((volumes, index) => (
```

> Syntax Error Unexpected Token, expected ,"

This code works if I remove one of the two `data.Values` mappings so I presume I am mapping this incorrectly *ie.* React doesn't like me mapping `data.Values` twice in a row. Any ideas?

```
<tr>
   <th className="hide">Date</th>
       {props.data.map((data, index) => (
          atIndex(index, 0) ? 
          data.Values.Prices.map(prices => (
               <th className="tableBorder"> {prices.name} </th>
          ))
          data.Values.Volumes.map((volumes, index) => (
               atIndex(index, 0) ?
               <th className="tableBorder" style={{ borderLeft:"2px solid #ffffff" }}> {volumes.name} </th>
                :
               <th className="tableBorder"> {volumes.name} </th>
           ))
                : null
           ))
         }
</tr>
```

Comment: if you are using container class then you have to use this.props... instead of just props

Comment: Using "export default props => (" so it's not an issue with the mappings themselves. Like I said, I remove one of the data.Values mappings and it works. Seems to be a clash between these two.

Comment: it looks like Curly brackets are not applied correctly

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to make two statements in a ternary operator - it has nothing to do with using two instances of `data.Values.Volumes.map`.

Consider rewriting this as an if/else statement.